# Java non static method playCompletely cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I've been trying to create a method (in a separate class) that takes a String as a parameter and uses a premade SoundEngine (a different class) object to play that file inputted as a string. This is the code I have so far. The problem comes up with
SoundEngine.playCompletely(file);

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AudioFileList
{
   // Field for a quantity of notes.
   private ArrayList<String> files;

   // Constructor that initializes the array field.
   public AudioFileList()
   {
        files = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   // Method to add file names to the collection.
   public void addFile(String file)
   {
        files.add(file);
   }

   // Method to return number of files in the collection.
   public int getNumberOfFiles()
   {
        return files.size();
   }

   // Method to print the strings in the collection.
   public void listFiles()
   {
        int index = 0;
        while(index < files.size())
        {
            System.out.println( index + ":" + files.get(index));
            index++;
            }
   }

   // Method that removes an item from the collection.
   public void removeFile(int fileNumber)
   {
        if(fileNumber < 0) 
            { 
                System.out.println ("This is not a valid file number");
            }
        else if(fileNumber < getNumberOfFiles())
            { 
                files.remove(fileNumber);
            }
        else 
            { 
                System.out.println ("This is not a valid file number");
            }
   }    

   // Method that causes the files in the collection to be played.

   public void playFile(String file)
   {
   SoundEngine.playCompletely(file);
   }

}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: When you're typing your question, to the right is a box labelled **How to Format**. Worth a read. I've taken an initial stab at formatting the code for you since I don't immediately recall whether you can edit your question with rep = 1...

Comment: The formatting of the question doesn't help us to anwser your question properly, fix it first, please. Use `101010` for this. // you should create an instance of `SoundEngine` before calling its non-static method, or make that method static.

Comment: @khachik sorry, what do you mean by `101010` ?

Comment: @thelost: That's the button that helps you quote code.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks :-) didn't know it as the "101010" button though that's what it says and looks like.

Answer (score 3):

`SoundEngine`'s `playCompletely` function is an **instance** function, not a class function. So instead of:

```
SoundEngine.playCompletely(file); // Compilation error
```

you want:

```
// First, create an instance of SoundEngine
SoundEngine se = new SoundEngine();

// Then use that instance's `playCompletely` function
se.playCompletely(file);
```